# Run a universal app as a 'legacy' iPhone app on an iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, universal-binary

I do most development testing on my iPad. When I test an iPhone app, it runs in 'compatibility' mode where the little iPhone app runs in a small window or x2 magnification. Now that I've created a universal app it runs as a native iPad app. For testing I'd like to use the simulated iPhone when I don't have an iPhone handy for testing.

How can I build the project so that the iPad will run the app in compatibility mode?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turns out it was really simple

- Get Info for the project target
- Change Targeted Device Family to iPhone

Comment: It's now "Devices" under "iOS Application Target".

Comment: When I do this, the iPad app runs in an iPhone-sized window. Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: After an extra 30 seconds of thinking, I realized I needed to change the value of "Main nib file base name (iPad)" in the target info to the same as the iPhone version of the same.

Answer (score -1):

You can't.  If the target is 3.2 SDK, then it will always run the simulator as an iPad. So your options are to debug on a device, or configure your app to be build under 3.1.3 so that the simulator will be an iPhone (too much trouble and unreliable).

Or hope for a later release with the option.